# AWS elb vs google cloud for multiple small nodejs mini-apps deployment

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, aws-elb

Currently i use AWS ELB `--single` instances do deploy & manage multiple versions of the same `nodejs` app (over 10), which differ only by the configuration. Each app is running some endless process 24/7. I want to be able to manage (start/stop/update) them separately and efficiently. Currently it's very easy to do so with `elb deploy` command.

However, the costs went seriously up lately (while the load increased just by 10-20%). About half of the cost is the data transfer and 40% is the EC2 instances themselves (`t2.nano`).

Would the use of Google Cloud be more cost efficient? and more importantly, is there a similar way do deploy and manage 10x instances of the same app? Sure when i finish reading all the docs, i might have an idea, but hoping to get some advise about the direction of research or probably about the solution itself.

Answer (score 1):

you can try google cloud run. here you can run containerized applications on a fully managed serverless platform. You might have to containerize your application.
But it can help you reduce the cost as  the min container can be 0 (zero) and if any to your app is there cloud run can automatically scale to meet the demand.